# How do I programatically close the tinymce dialog in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

If I type into the Javascript console:
tinyMCEPopup.close();

It returns:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'windowManager' of undefined

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

From within the popup, I call the following:

```
parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.close(window);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
win.ed.windowManager.close(this);
//where
//win is parent window
//ed is tinyMCE object
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Im just working in the global space in the javascript console:
    win.ed.windowManager.close(this);
    ReferenceError: win is not defined

tinyMCE.WindowManager.close(this)
TypeError: Object function (f){var g=this;g.editor=f;g.onOpen=new a(g);g.onClose=new a(g);g.params={};g.features={}} has no method 'close'

tinymce.WindowManager.close(this)
TypeError: Object function (f){var g=this;g.editor=f;g.onOpen=new a(g);g.onClose=new a(g);g.params={};g.features={}} has no method 'close'